# Why would the lights on a ceiling fan not work after a power outage even though the fan does?

Tags: ceiling-fan

Why does the ceiling fan work but the lights on it will not turn on after a power outage?

Comment: There's no simple answer; you'll have to debug it step by step. It may be a completely unrelated failure that you just happened to notice after the power failure.  I presume you've already tried replacing the bulbs.

Comment: Are there any type of remote, or other special controls involved (dimmers, timers, anything with sensitive electronics, etc)? What caused the power outage?

Answer (score 1):

Could be a number of things.

I've had ceiling fans that are on two different circuits: one for the fan, and one for the light. It could be that the breaker is thrown on one circuit but not on the other.

It could also be that a surge caused the outage, and that burned out the bulb, the switch inside the fan, the switch on the wall, or any add-ons such as wireless remotes.

It could be that the light is on a 3-way switch, and someone flipped the other switch in trying to get the lights to work during the outage.